# Neural Network - global error affected by heuristic

Tags: neural-network

I want to apply neural network in very unusual way (It is a part of my research in master thesis). For this example, assume backpropagation neural network(NN). Also I am not quite sure if this is a correct SO forum, so please redirect me elsewhere if needed.

Lets assume we have an input vector *i* for NN, output vector *o* and reference output vector *r*. Also input and output vector are represented with vector of same length (And in our case, they have same semantic meaning, both are 'some configurations').

In **standard** way our global error is calculated like half of squared distance between reference and output vector for input vector *i*

> ((1/2)(*o*-*r*)^2)

In **my case** I do not have a reference output vector *r*. Instead I do have a function *F(o)* which rates NN output and returns % of output quality. ( To be more specific its result is a percentage of coverage ). And **finally** to complicate this a bit more, my utility function is not a function F(o), but an increase in coverage between input and output (F(o)-F(i)). How to modify global error funcion in such way that my utility function will be taken into account?.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, yours is a problem of maximization. You can use a genetic algorithm to maximize a set of networks, using you function F(o) as the scoring function to maximize by GA.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes you seem to understand the problem correctly. If I understood correctly, I should use GA instead of NN, or what do you mean with "maximizing set of networks"?

Comment: Not instead, together. Use a population for GA composed by a set of ANNs for your problem. Evaluate each net using the error generate by the net. GA will optimize the set of nets to maximize your score. The final result will be a set of optimized nets.

Comment: Sorry for late response, still it is unclear for me how do I teach my ANNs since I have no reference vectors. How do I affect weights?